# How to exclude dependency from a Fat Jar that creates version conflicts

Tags: java, gradle, build, fatjar

I am using an old fat jar in my project that uses old version of "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" jar.

The problem is that java class loader is failing to load my project with error
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.JacksonFeatureSet com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.getReadCapabilities()'"

This is because of old version of faster xml in fat jar.

I tried to exclude old version by following code snippets but it does not work. It still injects old version of fasterxml.

`compile('OLD FAT JAR DEPENDENCY') { exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core' }`

Could anyone suggest how to remove dependency from fat jar.